# Do records of functions have low memory footprint?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, record

Supposedly I want to have a `Reservation` to work with its `deposit`. There are many types of `Reservation`, such as reserving for Normal guests, or VIPs,... (e.g. VIP can get higher discount when depositing large amount of money, etc.)

```
namespace RoomBooking

type ReservationType =
    | Normal
    | VIP
    | Custom
    ...

type Reservation =
    { ``type`` : ReservationType
      incrDeposit : decimal -> unit
      decrDeposit : decimal -> unit }

module Reservation =

    let init deposit = function
        | Normal | Custom as t ->
            let mutable deposit = if deposit > 0m then deposit else 0m
            { ``type`` = t
              incrDeposit = fun d -> if d > 0m then deposit <- deposit + d
              decrDeposit = fun d -> if deposit > d then deposit <- deposit + d }
        | VIP ->
        ...

    let customInit incrDeposit decrDeposit =
        { ``type`` = Custom
          incrDeposit = incrDeposit
          decrDeposit = decrDeposit }
```

If I have lots of records, would the application have high memory footprint?

As for the example above, I make a private mutable variable to store money, which is bad. How can I make the functions work without exposing `deposit` to the outside?

Comment: "High" is a relative term -- a high memory footprint compared to what?

Comment: @ildjarn Such as putting `incrDeposit`, `decrDeposit` functions into module `Reservation`, and only using record type to save data `type Reservation = { ``type``:ReservationType; deposit:decimal }`

Comment: You will absolutely spend more memory on a record of functions than a record of values: you still have to store those same values somewhere (in a closure), but now you also have to allocate memory for the function pointers themselves. However, I must warn: beware premature optimization!

Comment: Why are you trying to redesign classes with mutable data using records?  The memory usage aspect of this question is completely premature because you should come up with a sensible design before even thinking about that.  That design should either embrace the functional paradigm and use immutable data/records or it should use classes with methods.  F# supports both of these things.  I don't understand why you are trying to create a custom hybrid of both that will confuse everyone who will ever read the code.